# Chromium build failure on windows 7 with vs2013 (warning as error)

Tags: chromium, ninja

I am trying to build chromium (browser) on 64 bit Windows with VS2013 express Desktop.
When I ran 'ninja' to build chromium, it fails with the following error:
"error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated"
Does anyone have any clue about what I have to do to avoid it?

The following is what comes out when I run 'ninja':

```
E:\chrome_build\depot_tools\src>ninja –C out\Debug chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out\Debug'
[352/18195] CXX obj\third_party\snappy\src\snappy.snappy-stubs-internal.obj
FAILED: ninja -t msvc -e environment.x86 -- "E:chrome_build\depot_tools\win_too
lchain\vs2013_files\VC\bin\cl.exe" /nologo /showInculdes /FC @obj\third_party\sn
appy\src\snappy.snappy-stubs-internal.obj.rsp /c ..\..\third_party\snappy\src\sn
appy-stubs-internal.cc /Foobj\third_party\snappy\src\snappy.snappy-stubs-interna
l.obj /Fdobj\third_party\snappy\snappy.cc.pdb
e:\chrome_build\depot_tools=src\third_party\snappy\src\snappy-stubs-internal.h :
 error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
e:\chrome_build\depot_tools=src\third_party\snappy\src\snappy-stubs-internal.h :
 warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the
current code page (949). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss
[352/18195] CXX obj\third_party\snappy\src\snappy.snappy.obj
FAILED: ninja -t msvc -e environment.x86 -- "E:chrome_build\depot_tools\win_too
lchain\vs2013_files\VC\bin\cl.exe" /nologo /showInculdes /FC @obj\third_party\sn
appy\src\snappy.snappy.obj.rsp /c ..\..\third_party\snappy\src\snappy.cc /Foobj\
third_party\snappy\src\snappy.snappy.obj /Fdobj\third_party\snappy\snappy.cc.pdb

e:\chrome_build\depot_tools=src\third_party\snappy\src\snappy-stubs-internal.h :
 error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
e:\chrome_build\depot_tools=src\third_party\snappy\src\snappy-stubs-internal.h :
 warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the
current code page (949). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss
[352/18195] CXX obj\device\hid\device_hid.hid_service_win.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

E:\chrome_build\depot_tools\src>
```

Answer (score 0):

e:\chrome_build\depot_tools=src\third_party\snappy\src\snappy-stubs-internal.h :
 warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the
current code page (949). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss

open the file with notepad.exe, or anything you like, save it with utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You cannot save it as UTF-8.  I got the same error as well, and I found that the file mentioned is already in UTF-8.  (There is some German text in the comments)  Also, ninja suggested to save the file in Unicode instead.

This is the error message I have got:

hash_tables.h : warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (950). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss

Same error appear now at several headers under src/testing/gtest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h and third_party/libusb/src/libusb/stderror.c

In additional, are you working on your compilation on a Windows machine?  I am doing the development on a Windows machine as well.  Guess most other users are using Linux instead.

=====

And I came across this when searching for other possible solutions:

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows#TOC-Build-failures-on-Vista

But I do not think the suggestion is wise.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
As you mentioned, most of people are using Linux, and I figured that I had to as well.
So, I am away from Windows for the development.
Thank you again Tom for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this warning, you need to change your Windows system code page to English or another SBCS code page. You can do this by `Control Panel - Regions - Administrative - Language for non-Unicode programs`.

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-dev/3DV8Huz5C0M/oyvU9flBqMYJ

Answer (score 0):

USE UTF8 WITH BOM

I suffer this when I build angle on win8